# $A \unlhd AB \mbox{ or } B \unlhd AB \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad AB \le G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A, B \le G$, Then do we have
$$
 A \unlhd AB \mbox{ or } B \unlhd AB 
\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
 AB \le G.
$$
If $A \unlhd AB$ and $ab, a'b' \in AB$, then $aba'b' = a(ba'b^{-1})bb' \in AB$
as $ba'b^{-1} \in A$ and $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1} a^{-1} = (b^{-1} a^{-1} b) b^{-1} \in AB$ as $b^{-1}a^{-1}b \in A$. So one direction is established.

But what about the other direction, if $AB \le G$ then one of $A$ or $B$
must be normal in $AB$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For example, take cyclic subgroups $C_2$ and $C_3$ of $S_3$ (so $C_3$ is normal but $C_2$ isn't) and let $G=S_3\times S_3$, $A=C_3\times C_2$, and $B=C_2\times C_3$.